# Error while installing pyomo inside Windows OS

Tags: conda, pyomo

I was trying to install `pyomo` using Python based conda software for my research work. It is giving this error:

```
Solving environment: failed 
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors 
are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

Can you suggest what can be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this a question for super user instead?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? That's conda telling you that it can't connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I am behind a proxy. To permanently set your proxies, follow the below steps:

(I assume you installed Python using Anaconda)

Go to C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/etc/

If it doesn’t already have a conda folder, create it.

If it doesn’t already have the folders activate.d and deactive.d, create them.

Also create env_vars.bat in both folders. Your end structure should look like the snapshot below:

[image]

In env_vars.bat in activate.d, paste the following (change it to your own proxies):

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.x.xx:xxxx/
set FTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.x.xx:xxxx/
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/
```

In env_vars.bat in deactivate.d, paste the following (leave the variables blank)):

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set FTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
```

Close and reopen your Anaconda Prompt to activate the changes.